# Scrolling to pixel number in a div with jquery

Tags: jquery

Having trouble finding the answer to this simple problem. I want to scroll to an exact pixel number as measured from the top of a div. This doesn't work:

```
$('#content').scrollTo(10000);
```

Comment: It will if you change `scrollTo` to [`scrollTop`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) and remove the extra `)` causing a syntax error. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: The problem was I only read the first part the doc page which said that scrollTo accepts no arguments. Oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will wanna use scrollTop

```
$("#content").scrollTop(10000);
```

The scrollTop() method sets or returns the vertical scrollbar position for the selected elements.

**When used to return the position:**

> This method returns the vertical position of the scrollbar for the
>   FIRST matched element.

**When used to set the position:**

> This method sets the vertical position of the scrollbar for ALL
>   matched elements.

Quoted from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_scrolltop.asp)

Answer (score 0):

[scrollTo()](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) is a jQuery plugin, not a native method. You want [scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/).